# Attempt to instantiate Date object is met with an error

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

I am attempting to instantiate a Date object in a google Script by doing this:

```
function addToCalendar(Sport, Date, Time){
var DSICalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById([VALID ID]);
var startDate = new Date();

}
```

var startDate = new Date();

However, my code is not compiling and I am seeing this error:

**TypeError: (class)@764e29c3 is not a function, it is undefined. (line 41, file "Code")**

How would I fix this?

Comment: Is this all your code? Seems very strange

Comment: @StefanOctavian I have updated my post with the rest of the code in the function I am attempting to instantiate the date object in.

Comment: @Lontronix what are you passing in Date parameters, could you rename it and check again.

Comment: @AayQue Nothing at this point, [this site](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) says it should set the Date to the current Date

Comment: Do you actually use square bracket notation for 'getCalendarById()' argument? There's nothing in your code that would hint at any errors.

Comment: @Lontronix rename Date to _Date in function parameter.

Comment: @AntonDementiev no, I just didn't want to show the actual id

Comment: @AayQue this: **var startDate = new _Date();** results in this error: **ReferenceError: "_Date" is not defined. (line 41, file "Code")**

Comment: Btw, what do you mean by "the code is not compiling"? JavaScript is not a compiled language. Do you get the error while attempting to save the script, or when executing this particular function?

Comment: @Lontronix I was talking about the other Date than this one.

Comment: @AayQue That fixed it, thanks!

Comment: @Lontronix could you mark it the answer?

Comment: @AntonDementiev I ended up fixing the error by change the name of the Date parameter in the function parameters.

Comment: @AayQue I will, but it can't be a comment. You need to submit it as an answer

Comment: yes, basically, you used the reserved word in JavaScript to assign a name to the function parameter. Kudos to @AayQue for noticing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are doing wrong is to pass `Date` as a parameter to the function, renaming the `Date` to `_Date` will fix the error.

```
function addToCalendar(Sport, _Date, Time){
    var DSICalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById([VALID ID]);
    var startDate = new Date();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter called Date that you are passing into the function is overwriting the standard Date object. When you call Date () it's trying to instantiate the object you are passing in rather than instantiating a standard Date object with the current time.